# extjs 6.5.* (1, 2) combobox bug on iPad and Google Chrome

Tags: ios, google-chrome, extjs, combobox, extjs6-modern

While testing my webapp on an iPad (**ios 10.3.3**) i came up to something that looks like a framework bug.

All the `combobox`es with `queryMode` set to `local` were not opening the dropdown popup on `combobox`'s `button` click.

(**Tested on Chrome v. 63.0.3238.73**)

I would add a fiddle but you can test it at:

[extjs 6.5.2 modern combobox, example usage](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.field.ComboBox.html)

and

[extjs 6.5.1 kitchensink modern, checkout form (Shipping Address -> State)](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/examples/kitchensink/?modern#form-checkout)

Anyone else faced that bug or is it a device problem?

Any known workarounds?

Comment: The same problem occurs when I'm using a nested grid. [Click!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029199/click-event-in-combobox-inside-rowexpander-not-working)

Comment: Check my answer. Maybe you can do something similar for your grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround and I am posting it in order to help someone with the same issue.

Adding a minHeight to the `floatedPicker` config solves the bug.

```
floatedPicker: {
    minHeight: 100 
}
```