# Click event in combobox inside Rowexpander Not Working

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs6-classic

I'm using a Nested grid with **Row Expander** plugin. everything is working fine but inside the rowexpander a combo box, which resides inside the 2nd grid, not dropping down when mouse click event is fired.

The combo working properly when the Down/Up arrow keys. This is happening only when I use Chrome/Mozilla.  Click event works fine with IE.